# Getting weird data using .val to get user input

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1988/

I have an input box. I'm trying to grab the data the user enters. It returns a bunch of code.

```
<input id="zip">
<input type="button" value="test" />

$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
 var temp=$('#zip').val;
    alert("function started");
    alert(temp);

});
```

Comment: It's `.val()`, not `.val`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually

```
var temp=$('#zip').val;
```

Should be:

```
var temp=$('#zip').val();
```

Comment: wow cant believe i missed something that easy. Long day i guess. Will accept answer when I can. Thank you very much!